# btrfs ioctl: get file checksums from userspace

Tags: linux, btrfs

I would like to obtain the BTRFS checksums related to the specific file, but unfortunately I have not found appropriate ioctl to perform this action. Is it possible to do? If so, how to do that? I need stored checksums to try to reduce CPU load in cases similar to rsync behaviour.

Comment: BTW, btrfs generates checksums for *blocks*, not for *files* (AFAIK).

Comment: That is exactly what I want: a list of checksums for blocks of the given file.

Comment: I've been skimming through the source code and I don't see any interface to get the checksum values.

Comment: Maybe this helps: search for `BTRFS_CSUM_TREE_OBJECTID` in `btrfs-debug-tree` sources: https://github.com/linsomniac/btrfs-progs/blob/17459dcc8cc9d54963cbfd844006340315b73e86/debug-tree.c I have no btrfs support on my kernel, so I can't check what it actually prints.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just now pushed this messy code into my github repo. https://github.com/Lakshmipathi/btrfs-progs/tree/dump_csum
Its not official code. I tested  for files between size 100K to 50GB. They seem to match.

Usage:

```
./btrfs-debug-tree -f /path/to/file /btrfs/partition
```

will create *csumdump* file at destination.

Example:

```
sudo ./btrfs-debug-tree -f /btrfs/50gbfile1 /dev/sda4
```

will create an output file-named '*/btrfs/50gbfile1.csumdump*' with csum of file blocks.

Note: I was trying this out for educational/learning purpose,so it comes with all usual disclaimers. Planning to cleanup this  code sometime this week.

If you plan to use, I would recommend you to test with following cases:

```
1) Create 20GB (or any file with size > 1KB) on /tmp/ 
2) mount your btrfs partition on /btrfs and copy file /tmp/file /btrfs/f1
3) Now dump the csum it will produce /btrfs/f1.csumdump
4) cp /tmp/file /btrfs/f2 and dump f2's csum.
5) Now compare f1.csumdump with f2.csumdump If they match, it seems to be 
working. If they didn't match something went wrong.
```

#### Update after almost 5 years!

New location: https://github.com/Lakshmipathi/dduper